# Generic Type Extension Method ToMultidimensionalArray

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm currently trying to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a 2-dimensional array of type T2 using an extension method with generic types. You should also be able to choose which properties of T you want to include into that array.

Here's what I got so far:

```
public static T2[][] ToMultidimensionalArray<T, T2>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int count, params string[] propNames)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        T2[][] resultArray = new T2[count][];
        int i = 0;
        int arrLength = propNames.Length;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            resultArray[i] = new T2[arrLength];
            int j = 0;
            foreach(string prop in propNames)
            {
                resultArray[i][j] = ((T)enumerator.Current).//How do I access the properties?
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
```

I'm having a problem accessing the properties of `enumerator.Current` within the `foreach`-Loop.

I'm using .NET-Framework 4.0.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: This will not work, since T does not know any special properties. 
Which framework are you targeting? Any chance to use dynamics (from .NET 4.0)?

Comment: Question updated. I am indeed using 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this problem can be solved using reflection:

```
public static T2[][] ToMultidimensionalArray<T, T2>(
                                                this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
                                                int count,
                                                params string[] propNames)
{
    T2[][] resultArray = new T2[count][];
    int i = 0;
    int arrLength = propNames.Length;
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        resultArray[i] = new T2[arrLength];
        int j = 0;
        foreach (string prop in propNames)
        {
            // Get the required property info using reflection
            var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop);
            // Extract the getter method of the property
            var getter = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
            // Invoke the getter and get the property value
            var value = getter.Invoke(item, null);
            // Cast the value to T2 and store in the array
            resultArray[i][j] = (T2) value;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

I understood the problem as having a `T`s collection where these objects have properties of `T2` type. The goal is to take the properties of each object and place them in a multidimensional array. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There's no need to correct you, because you aren't wrong, quite the contrary! Thanks for this useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean 
(T2)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop).GetValue(enumerator.Current, null);

But I can't understand what you want. I don't think this method can work.